# Javascript event before leaving page unless special link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I would like to execute a function before page is unloaded to send data to my Analytics tool. When the user leaves the page via a special link i don't want the event to be executed.

I do only know:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ ... }
```

Is there a way I can deactivate the function when unload happens via a special link?

Comment: Why dont you just put some If statement in the function that checks if the link was clicked, maybe via a boolean that what changed when the link was clicked.

Comment: Out of topic but don't forget you have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API that is the proper way of doing things on unload